# react native Bluetooth printer printPic did not print image just characters with pr3 intermec printer

Tags: react-native

hello this is my code when printPic i got weird characters

import {
BluetoothManager,
BluetoothEscposPrinter,
} from 'react-native-bluetooth-escpos-printer'; version '0.0.5'

with printer type pr3 intermec

can you help me please i am stuck here

printIt = async () => {
const imageUri = await this.refs.viewShot2.capture({
result: 'tmpfile',
width: 1000,
});

```
const base64 = await FileSystem.readFile(imageUri, {
  encoding: 'base64',
});

await BluetoothEscposPrinter.printerInit();
await BluetoothEscposPrinter.printerAlign(
  BluetoothEscposPrinter.ALIGN.CENTER,
);
console.log(`base64`, base64);

try {
  await BluetoothEscposPrinter.printPic(base64, {
    width: 100,
    left: 0,
  });
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e || 'ERROR');
  console.log(e);
}
```

};

```
  return (
    <View style={styles.Maincontainer}>
      <ViewShot ref="viewShot2" style={styles.body}>
        <Image
          resizeMode="contain"
          source={require('../../../../assists/img/cloud.jpg')}
          style={{width: 100, height: 100}}
        />
      </ViewShot>
      <View
        style={{
          width: '100%',
          padding: 10,
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
        }}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.printIt} style={styles.button}>
          <Text style={styles.printText}>print</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
```

[issue image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xl8aw.jpg)

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).